# Creating a round button for my WPF app in visual studio 2013. Problem here is onPaint() Method generate error asking me to enter some valid parameters

Tags: c#

Creating a round button for my WPF app in visual studio 2013. The problem here is onPaint() Method generates error asking me to enter some valid parameters.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CurrencyTeller
{
    class CircularButton:Button
    {
        protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            GraphicsPath grpath = new GraphicsPath();
            grpath.AddEllipse(0,0,ClientSize.Width,ClientSize.Height);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grpath);
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
        }

    }
}
```

> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CurrencyTeller.PaintEventArgs' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, youre creating a Forms control, not a WPF control. Create a new "WPF User Control" in your Project and port your button to the template. Beware that **Windows.Forms controls dont work in a WPF enviroment.**
Best you look at some WPF Control tutorial.